# Round off a number to display without decimals

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two values to display. Both of these contain decimals. I would like to round these numbers off so that the decimal will be eliminated. I tried to hide the decimal but the rounding off is not implemented. How do I do this ?

```
public Text minimumValue;
public Text maximumValue;

 void Start() {
      minimumValue.text = (54.7f / 100).ToString ("F0");
      maximumValue.text = (24.97f / 100).ToString ("F0");

}
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "round off" .. for `54.7f / 100` do you want to get `0` or `1`?

Comment: its 0.547, so that rounds off to 0.55 and it should be 1. :)

Comment: Well, it comes out as 1 when I try it... `Console.WriteLine((54.7f / 100).ToString("F0"));`

Comment: How about [`Math.Round`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=net-5.0)?

Comment: Looks like it currently does exactly what you expect: https://dotnetfiddle.net/anMgHc

Comment: it was just an example i presented here, but the values could be different

Comment: So the example you gave doesn't actually have a problem. Perhaps it would be better if you gave an example which *does* have a problem?

Comment: @Andre that's rounding "up" not "off" for me, that's why I asked ;)

Comment: ah sorry my english failed here. I meant rounding up yes :D

Comment: @Andre so for the `24.97f / 100` you want to get `0` or `1`? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To round *up* you use [`Math.Ceiling`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.ceiling?view=net-5.0)

```
public Text minimumValue;
public Text maximumValue;

 void Start() {
      minimumValue.text = Math.Ceiling(54.7f / 100).ToString ("F0");
      maximumValue.text = Math.Ceiling(24.97f / 100).ToString ("F0");

}
```

This will make both your examples round to `1` as shown here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/sGrjqQ

Comment: I doubt that OP actually wants to round up **always** ... Also for Unity you might probably be using [`Mathf.Ceil`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Ceil.html) instead which works directly with `float` instead of `double`

Comment: Thanks yes I ended up using Mathf.Ceil :) It works as i want :)